# Time Efficient Code for reading words from a text file and sort them in increasing order of their occurence?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, time-complexity

I have a text file in which I have repeating words,I need to find the total occurence of the word and sort them in Increasing Order.

Below is the code I am Using:

```
public class showWordsInDecOrder {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Map<String, Integer> fileData = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "C:\\short.txt"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = line.split("\\s");
                for (String sp : split) {
                    if (fileData.get(sp) != null) {
                        fileData.put(sp, fileData.get(sp) + 1);
                    } else
                        fileData.put(sp, 1);
                }
            }
            ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>> sortedList = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(
                    fileData.entrySet());
            Collections.sort(sortedList, new Compare1());
            System.out.println(sortedList);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Compare1 implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
        return o1.getValue() - o2.getValue();
    }

}
```

If I have n rows and n words in each row,time complexity here will be O(Square of n).Can anyone please suggest me better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the real complexity of your code is O(n*logn). Which n is the total number of words in the file. Also the complexity is mostly from the sort, rather than parse the file .

The way you calculate the complexity, as n rows and n words per row would result in n^2 words in total. With n^2 words, it would take n^2*log(n^2) time to sort, if that make sense.. I.e. the sort is still the most expensive part

The algorithm itself is pretty efficient to me. Hopefully others know if there is a better way.